# How do I drill into a complex model using Glimpse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, metadata, glimpse

I am using the Metadata tab in Glimpse to view a model for my view in an MVC application. My model has a collection property, and I need to inspect the individual objects within that collection.  It appears that Glimpse can only tell me the type of collection, but it cannot let me drill into the objects and inspect their values.  Is this correct?  Is there some other way to get at this data?